# Auth login test using protractor and Azure AD

Tags: angularjs, azure, protractor

I am trying to authnticate user with an e2e test. I am not able to get this working. The test never waits after the button click on Azure AD login page.

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {

var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;



it('should greet the named user', function() {
    var driver = ptor.driver;

    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1500, 1000);

    browser.driver.get('https://test.azurewebsites.net/test-ui/');
    driver.findElement(By.id("cred_userid_inputtext")).sendKeys("TestUser@test.onmicrosoft.com");

    // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'pwd' (Password)

    // Enter Password on the element found by the above desc.

    driver.findElement(By.id("cred_password_inputtext")).sendKeys("23423421asdasd");

    // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element

    ptor.findElement(By.id("cred_sign_in_button")).click();

    browser.driver.sleep(50000);

    expect(element(by.id('username')).getText()).toEqual("Test User");
});
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the Azure AD login page needs are double click for the button. hence

```
   var btn = ptor.findElement(By.id("cred_sign_in_button"));

    btn.click();
    btn.click();
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to login by clicking the button from waiting for loading after fill in the form.

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("cred_password_inputtext")).sendKeys("23423421asdasd");

    browser.driver.sleep(2000);

    ptor.findElement(By.id("cred_sign_in_button")).click();
```

Comment: What is the issue or what are you trying to do?